# How to load all image files from a directory path supplied as a props to a vuejs component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, components

I am trying to create a [vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) SFC component (named `Gallery.vue`) with `location` as a props, which should accept a string path to image directory where all image files are kept.

Am looking forward to load all the image files using webpack so that I can compress and optimize the images later.

So far, I have this setup which **only** works for harcoded paths, but throws an exception when I try to pass a value from variable to it (exact error mentioned below).

Component File **Gallery.vue**

```js
// templated ... skipped
...
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    loc: {
      type: String,
      default: "assets",
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    images: "",
  }),
  mounted() {
    console.log("IMAGE LOC: " + this.loc);
    this.images = this.importAll(
      // require.context("../../assets", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)   // WORKS
      /**
       * FIXME Error in mounted hook:
       * "TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function"
       */
      require.context(this.loc, false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)     // DOESNT WORK
    );
    console.log(this.images);
  },
  methods: {
    importAll(r) {
      return r.keys().map(r);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Usage in Content files as `<Gallery loc="./page1/assets/" />` or `<Gallery :loc="location" />`

How can I variablize the path and pass it as a props to component such that webpack can still read and later transform all the images at the location?

What could be the alternate dynamic solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Usage:**

- for string constant

```js
<Gallery loc="./page1/assets/" />
```

- with variable

```js
// in the data section
const location = './page1/assets/'
// in the template section
<Gallery :loc="location" />
```

Let me know if that's the fix

Comment: The issue is with webpack `require.context()` call. Passing props to components works just fine for me. Problem is as soon as `require.context()` sees a variable values it screams out `"TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function"`. This is what I am trying to find a solution for

Comment: Oh ok I see now